# Given an integer, compute its Levenshtein code

Tags: code-golf, sequence, binary

<sup>*Disclaimer: Levenshtein coding is completely unrelated to the [Levenshtein edit distance metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).*</sup>

<Insert long story about why Levenshtein codes need to be calculated here.>

## The code

[Levenshtein coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_coding) is a system of assigning binary codes to nonnegative integers that retains some weird property in probability which isn't relevant for this challenge. We will denote this code as *L*(*n*). Wikipedia describes this as a five-step process:

1. Initialize the step count variable *C* to 1.
2. Write the binary representation of the number without the leading `1` to the beginning of the code.
3. Let *M* be the number of bits written in step 2.
4. If *M* is not 0, increment *C*, repeat from step 2 with *M* as the new number.
5. Write *C* `1` bits and a `0` to the beginning of the code.

However, the code can also be described recursively:

1. If the number is 0, then its code is `0`.
2. Write the binary representation of the number without the leading `1` to the beginning of the code.
3. Let *M* be the number of bits written in step 2.
4. Write *L*(*M*) to the beginning of the code.
5. Write a `1` bit to the beginning of the code.

For those who prefer examples, here is the recursive process for *L*(87654321), with [image] denoting concatenation:

[image]

## The challenge

Write a program or function that, given a number *n*, outputs the bitstring *L*(*n*) in any reasonable format (this includes returning a number with said bits). Standard loopholes are, as always, disallowed.

## Examples

Input: `5`

Output: `1110001`

Input: `30`

Output: `111100001110`

Input: `87654321`

Output: `111110000101001001110010111111110110001`

Input: `0`

Output: `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḣ;LÑ$;
BÇṀ¡
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4biiO0zDkSQ7CkLDh-G5gMKh&input=&args=ODc2NTQzMjE) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4biiO0zDkSQ7CkLDh-G5gMKhCsOH4oKsRw&input=&args=NSwgMzAsIDg3NjU0MzIxLCAw).

#### How it works

The submission consists of a pair of mutually recursive links.

```
BÇṀ¡    Main link. Argument: n

B       Convert n to binary.
   ¡    Execute...
 Ç        the helper link...
  Ṁ       m times, where m is the maximum of n's binary digits.

Ḣ;LÑ$;  Helper link. Argument: A (array of binary digits)

Ḣ       Head; remove and return the first element of A.
    $   Combine the two links to the left into a monadic chain.
  L       Yield the length (l) of A without its first element.
   Ñ      Call the main link with argument l.
 ;      Concatenate the results to both sides.
     ;  Append the tail of A.
```

Answer (score 8):

## Haskell, 70 bytes

```
b 0=[]
b n=b(div n 2)++[mod n 2]
f 0=[0]
f n|1:t<-b n=1:f(length t)++t
```

Defines a function `f : Int -> [Int]`. For example, `f 5 == [1,1,1,0,0,0,1]`.

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 49 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and'1%s'%f(len(bin(n))-3)+bin(n)[3:]
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Is8Hz5).

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 61 bytes

```
f@0={0};f@n_:=Join[{1},f@Length@#,#]&@Rest@IntegerDigits[n,2]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can save a few bytes by defining a unary operator `±` instead of a function `f`.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```js
f=n=>(s=n.toString(2)).replace(1,_=>1+f(s.length-1))
```

```html
<input type=number oninput=o.textContent=f(+this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Arnauld.

Comment: I think you can safely use `replace(1,...` instead of `replace(/1/,...` => 52 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
L&bX1.Bbyslb
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%26bX1.Bbyslby&input=87654321&debug=0)

(The `y` at the end is to run the resulting function on the input)

Explanation:

```
L&bX1.Bbyslb
L               def y(b):
 &b             If b is 0, return 0. This is returned as an int, but will be cast
                to a string later.
          lb    Take the log of b
         s      Floor
        y       Call y recursively
   X1           Insert at position 1 into
     .Bb        Convert b to binary.
```

Answer (score 1):

## SQF, 110

Recursive function:

```
f={params[["i",0],["l",[]]];if(i<1)exitWith{[0]};while{i>1}do{l=[i%2]+l;i=floor(i/2)};[1]+([count l]call f)+l}
```

Call as: `[NUMBER] call f`

**Note this doesn't actually work for 87654321 or other large numbers due to a bug in the ArmA engine. Although it will probably be fixed soon, and should work according to spec.**

([This Ticket Here](https://feedback.bistudio.com/T119933))

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <strike>116</strike> 114 bytes

```
<?$f=function($i)use(&$f){$b=decbin($i);return!$b?0:preg_replace('/^1/',1 .$f(~~log10($b)),$b);};echo$f($argv[1]);
```

Provide the number as the first argument.

### Update:

- Saved a byte by replacing `strlen($b)-1` with `~~log10($b)` (finally understood why everybody else was using logarithm) and another by concatenating differently.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 38 bytes

Very similar to [Neil's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89846/11261).

```
f=->n{("%b"%n).sub(/1\K/){f[$'.size]}}
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/CnhQ

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8 (Full Program), <s>257</s> 249 bytes

```
interface M{static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{int i=0,j;while((j=System.in.read())>10)i=i*10+j-48;System.out.print(L(i));}static String L(int i){if(i==0)return "0";String s=Integer.toString(i,2);return "1"+L(s.length()-1)+s.substring(1);}}
```

Readable Version w/ Explanation (It's mostly just recursion):

```
interface M {
    static void main(String[]a) throws Exception { // Using Exception is unadvised in real coding, but this is Code Gold
        int i = 0, j; // i stores the input; j is a temporary variable
        while ((j = System.in.read()) > 10) // Read the input to j and stop if it is a newline. Technically this stops for tabulators as well, but we shouldn't encounter any of those...
            i = i * 10 + j - 48; // Looping this step eventually reads the whole number in from System.in without using a reader (those take up a lot of bytes)
        System.out.print(L(i)); // Make a method call
    }

    static String L(int i) { // This gets the actual Levenshtein Code
        if (i == 0)
            return "0"; // The program gets a StackOverflowException without this part
        String s = Integer.toString(i, 2); // Shorter than toBinaryString
        return "1" + L(s.length() - 1) + s.substring(1); // Write in the first character (which is always a one), followed by the next L-code, followed by the rest of the binary string
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**: *Saved 8 bytes*: The first character of the binary string is *always* 1; therefore, rather than using `s.charAt(0)`, a better option is simply `"1"`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 14 bytes

```
?ö:1Ṡ+o₀LtḋΘøI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9odXNr//8/w7Y6MeG5oCtv4oKATHThuIvOmMO4Sf///zU)

Uses a simple recursive approach. (Dennis's double recursion is insane.)

Comment: Nice! I tried answering this challenge myself but had trouble with the inference.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Somehow making a `[0]` list was difficult. :D