# Prefix code generator

Tags: code-golf, binary, open-ended-function, coding-theory

In this challenge, we consider an encoding from positive integers (up to a limit) to binary sequences. Some examples:

```
A. 1 -> 00, 2 -> 01, 3 -> 10, 4 -> 11

B. 1 -> 0, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 01

C. 1 -> (empty sequence)
```

A [prefix code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) is a coding where no code is a prefix of another. `B` is not a prefix code because the code for 1 (`0`) is a prefix of that for 3 (`01`). [Fibonacci coding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/222676/78410) and [Elias omega coding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/219109/78410) are examples of prefix codes that can encode all positive integers.

It is possible to construct a prefix code where 1 encodes to a code of length \$l_1\$, 2 to \$l_2\$, ..., \$n\$ to \$l_n\$ if the sum of \$\tfrac{1}{2}\$ raised to the power of each length does not exceed 1, i.e. \$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\tfrac{1}{2^{l_i}}} \le 1\$. Your task is to construct such a prefix code where \$l_1, \cdots, l_n\$ is the input.

The following I/O are allowed:

- Take the list as input, and output the list or mapping of encodings for each positive integer
- Take the list and a number to encode as input, and output the encoding for the given number

Each encoding (binary sequence) can be given as a list or a string. Outputting as a single integer is not allowed, as leading zeros are not representable. You can choose to output an encoding for \$0, \cdots, n-1\$ instead of \$1, \cdots, n\$.

#### Examples

```
[0] -> {1 -> ""}
[1, 1] -> {1 -> "0", 2 -> "1"}
[2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5] ->
  {1 -> "11"
   2 -> "011"
   3 -> "0011"
   4 -> "1011"
   5 -> "00011"
   6 -> "10011"
   7 -> "01011"}
[3, 3, 3, 1, 3] ->
  {1 -> "101"
   2 -> "111"
   3 -> "110"
   4 -> "0"
   5 -> "100"}
[5, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2] ->
  {1 -> "10101"
   2 -> "1011"
   3 -> "000"
   4 -> "01"
   5 -> "10100"
   6 -> "1001"
   7 -> "001"
   8 -> "11"}
```

Comment: Is it OK if the solution fails for lengths greater than 53 due to floating-point inaccuracies?

Comment: @CommandMaster Yes, that's fine.

Comment: Since the codes may be assigned to any of those with their length may we output just the unsorted codes (e.g. from shortest to longest)?

Comment: ...or even stronger could we assume the code lengths are provided ordered?

Comment: @JonathanAllan No to both. I like the golf you did there though :)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 21 bytes

```
āø{ø`soDzηO>*<b€¦sākè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SOPhHdWHdyQU57tUndvub6dlk/Soac2hZcVHGrMPr/j/P9pUR8FER8FYR8FIRwHBjgUA)

Uses the same idea as arithmetic coding. Fails for lengths greater than 53 due to floating-point inaccuracies.

If we can output sorted by length, we can we 12 bytes:

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
{oDzηO>*<b€¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/Ot@l6tx2fzstm6RHTWsOLfv/P9pUR8FER8FYR8FIRwHBjgUA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
eƤ€`Ḅ=QƑẠ
Ø.ṗŒpÇƇṪ
```

A monadic Link that accepts the lengths and yields a list of prefix-codes in the same order.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9qZWxsef//Zcak4oKsYOG4hD1RxpHhuqAKw5gu4bmXxZJww4fGh@G5qv///1syLDMsNCw0LDFd)**

Save a byte by outputting symbols \$1\$ and \$2\$ by replacing `Ø.` with `2`.

#### How?

```
eƤ€`Ḅ=QƑẠ - Link 1: isValid?: list of codes, Assignment
   `      - use {Assignment} as both arguments of:
  €       -   for each Code in {Assignment}:
 Ƥ        -     for each prefix of {Code}:
e         -       exists in {Assignment}?
    Ḅ     - convert {each exists-in vector} from binary
              -> PrefixFoundIds, a list of ints
                 ...a value is greater than 1 when a prefix was in Assignments
                    otherwise it equals 1 (only the full code was in Assignments)
       Ƒ  - is {Assignments} invariant under?:
      Q   -   deduplication
                -> AllDifferent = 0 if there are repeats, 1 if not
     =    - {PrefixFoundIds} equals {AllDifferent} (vectorises)
        Ạ - all?

Ø.ṗŒpÇƇṪ - Main Link: list of integers, CodeLengths
Ø.       - [0,1]
  ṗ      - Cartesian product {CodeLengths} (vectorises)
             -> all codes for each of the respective lengths
   Œp    - Cartesian product
             -> all possible Assignments of codes
      Ƈ  - filter keep those {Assignments} for which:
     Ç   -   call Link 1 as a monad - f(Assignment)
       Ṫ - tail
```

---

### 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) (non-compliant)

Less brute force, so much faster, but outputs the prefix codes sorted by their lengths. Again `Ø.` could be replaced with `2` to save a byte. If the input were guaranteed to be sorted too, then `2ṗeƤẸ¥ÐḟḢṭð@ƒḟ` does the job at \$14\$ bytes.

```
Ø.ṗeƤẸ¥ÐḟḢṭ
Ṣç@ƒḟ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDL2HO6enHlvycNeOQ0sPT3i4Y/7DHYse7lzL9XDnosPLHY5NAor8//8/2kwHPzTSMYwFAA)**

#### How?

```
Ø.ṗeƤẸ¥ÐḟḢṭ - Link 1: integer NextCodeLength, list of codes, FoundAlready
Ø.          - [0,1]
  ṗ         - Cartesian power {NextCodeLength} -> PotentialCodes
       Ðḟ   - filter discard those for which:
      ¥     -   last two links as a dyad - f(PotentialCode, FoundAlready)
    Ƥ       -     for prefixes of {PotentialCode}
   e        -       exists in {FoundAlready}?
     Ẹ      -     any?
         Ḣ  - head -> first valid PotentialCode
          ṭ - tack to {FoundAlready}

Ṣç@ƒḟ - Main Link: list of integers, CodeLengths
Ṣ     - sort {CodeLengths}
    ḟ - {CodeLengths} filter discard {CodeLengths} -> [] (initial FoundAlready)
   ƒ  - starting with {[]} reduce {sorted CodeLengths} by:
  @   -   with swapped arguments:
 ç    -     call the dyadic helper above, Link 1 = f(NextCodeLength, FoundAlready)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 88 bytes

```python
lambda s,k=0,r=2:{j:bin(r:=(r<<-k+(k:=i))-1)[3:]for i,j in sorted(zip(s,range(len(s))))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZHRToMwFIbjLU9x0qs2FtPCpgsZew4T3AXLwHVDIKVqdOFJ9GKJ0XfSp_EUSoRJTkj__n_P1wNvX_WL2VXl6SOP7z4fTe4vvm-L9GGzTaHhh1hwHQfRcR9tVEl1FFO9XPqHS3qIYsWYL1kSRuu80qD4HlQJTaVNtqWvqqYN12l5n9EiK2nD8Gld_8zmC5uuavQEizxQORRXjUm1aZ6V2VGSELsNCmJr1IUylPgrwhKxxpzG_szZ2VNaUGVVrVVpqOI5StbDTj8X73gE_BUcpX0T0nqJ5CDHe4JwCLqVtHbAIeQw62rel00jweWlJCjcEeFU2KtBzvrkIOfOHfS1swd943pZjVcIuytg4VXDM7gY0-WELqUYwcWIjCTbd94NhX2Dbi63_geYIs4nnDDkBCKd-TfeeDqnFsNHbL3-L_0C)

Takes a list of integers and returns a dictionary.

### How?

Sorts the prescribed lengths and then simply counts down binary numbers of that length appending zeros when the length increases.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 115 bytes

A simple but quite long algorithm.

```javascript
a=>a.map((v,i)=>(h=x=>b.some(s=>c.match("^"+s)+s.match("^"+c),c=x.toString(2).padStart(v,0))?h(-~x):b[i]=c)``,b=[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzNCoMwEITvfQrxtEtj8KdeCmsfwqNYjKl/RY2YIJ766jbYHkoRvsPszOw8xSK0nLvJeKN6VFtNm6BE8EFMAAvrkBJoaaWk5FoNFWhKpA2NbMG9u2eNZ/1zSmSSVm5UauZubCBEPolHasRs7JiPeGvBe614LbMuJ4lFwUrKctykGrXqK96rBmrI/Bzx9OcFzAkO7JA5EXMuO/GHg1a0tyx2JTrI4/3f5uE@8dW2uL0B)

#### Method

We process all entries in the input order. For each entry, we simply start with \$x=0\$ and increment it while \$x\$ is a prefix of a previous output or a previous output is a prefix of \$x\$, in left-padded binary format.

#### Note

Because \$x\$ is actually initialized to `['']`, `x.toString(2).padStart(0,0)` returns an empty string rather than `"0"`, which is the expected behavior for the edge case `a = [0]`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 30 bytes

```
→Ｆ⊕⌈θ«Ｆ⌕Ａθι«§≔θκΦ⍘ⅈ²μ→»Ｍⅈ→»θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY49C4MwEIbn@CtuvEC69GOpkx0EB6G0S0EcgqYamkSMqQjF356mCi0dDo7n3o@rWm6rjivv824UeLzIpnU0ju6dBcxMZYUWxokacz5J/dTYU0rhFZFFkEpTJ0phz0CumCTDIBuTuMzUYvocHgxSqZyweOKDuDorTYM3pAy2YTQNZYT8l5M5Wski@@I5OgezCy/E3hfFgcGewS7kMPjtZek3o3oD) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
→
```

Start with a next code number of `1`, but all the codes will have their leading `1` removed again later.

```
Ｆ⊕⌈θ«
```

Loop over all possible code lengths.

```
Ｍⅈ→
```

Double the next code number.

```
Ｆ⌕Ａθι«
```

Loop over all indices with this length.

```
§≔θκΦ⍘ⅈ²μ
```

Generate the code of this length, but remove the leading `1`.

```
→
```

Increment the next code number.

```
»»θ
```

Output the resulting codes.